# Restricting results of a many to many joined query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three tables like this (simplified version):

```
Object
---------------
ID | ObjectName
---------------

Category
-----------------
ID | CategoryCode
-----------------

ObjectCategory
---------------------
ObjectID | CategoryID
---------------------
```

How can I select `ObjectName` and `CategoryCode` for all objects who **don't** belong to certain `CategoryCode`s? I can't just add a `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN`ed query on all three tables as it will ignore the intended restriction as long as an object belongs to at least one allowed `CategoryCode`.

EDIT: I also need to select `CategoryCode` from `Category` table, a select only on `Object` table is not enough

Comment: I think you *can* use a join, and i think it will be faster than the NOT EXISTS and NOT IN solutions. The trick is to use an OUTER JOIN and include the category codes you want to search for in the ON condition, and use the WHERE to see if the corresponding object category is NULL (ie, if it doens't exist). See my answer below

Comment: Re-reading your question, I am wondering - did you mean that you don't want to see the objects in case they match any or all of the categories you supply?

Comment: I need to exclude every object that matches any of the supplied categories

Comment: Ok. I amended my answer with two alterenative solutions. Let me know it that works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for `NOT EXISTS`

```
select       o1.*, c1.*
from         object            o1
inner join   object_category   oc1
on           o1.id           = oc1.object_id
inner join   category c1
on           oc1.category_id = c1.id
where not exists (
            select null
            from       object_category oc2
            inner join category        c2
            on         oc2.category_id = c2.id
            where      c2.name in ('code1',  'code1')
            and        oc2.object_id = o1.id
)
```

With little effort this can be rewritten to an equivalent NOT IN subquery (not shown)

In mySQL, subqueries, especially correlated subqueries like the EXISTS and NOT IN solutions can be quite slow. Alternative is to try a LEFT JOIN and a GROUP BY:

```
select      o1.*, c1.*
from        object                 o1
inner join  object_category        oc1
on          o1.id = oc1.object_id
inner join  category               c1
on          oc1.category_id = c1.id
left join   object_category        oc2
on          o1.id = oc2.object_id
left join   category               c2
on          oc2.category_id = c2.id
and         c2.name in ('code1', 'code1' )
group by    o1.id, c1.id
having      count(c2.id) = 0
```

Comment: I need to **exclude** certain categories

Comment: kemp: have you tried? this query excludes categories çode1 and code2

Comment: I get `NULL` in `CategoryCode` field

Comment: Thanks for your edits, will try those queries as soon as I get back to work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ObjectName 
FROM Objects 
    WHERE ObjectID NOT IN (
           SELECT ObjectID 
           FROM ObjectCategory AS a 
           JOIN Category AS b 
                ON a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
           WHERE CategoryCode = 'yourcodehere')
```

Haven't tested it, but this should get the names of all the ID's of the Objects that are not connected to a certain CategoryCode

Comment: I need to select CategoryCode too

Comment: Yes, I saw that in your edit... :) You could first select the distinct codes and then loop over them with this query, or you could use Roland's code below.